# Rostopic pub from master (one laptop) to nodes (other laptop)

Tags: ros-kinetic, roscore, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have the following configuration:

- laptop 1 that is the master (it runs "roscore") - it doesn't have the package or messages used by nodes
- laptop 2 that has two running nodes

I try to use "rostopic pub -1 /input_topic component_adder/inputMsg -- '15' '13'" from laptop 1 (master) to the topic "input_topic" from one node from laptop 2 but I get the following error: **ERROR: invalid message type: component_adder/inputMsg.
If this is a valid message type, perhaps you need to type 'rosmake component_adder'**

I want to mention that in laptop 1 (master) I don't have the messages or anything related to project. I exported ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP properly, nodes can see the master because I can use the same rostopic command from above in laptop 2 and it works.

Please let me know if there's a way to use the rostopic command from above in laptop 1 (master) without having the package from laptop 2 (nodes).

Thank you,

Eduard.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307679/rostopic-pub-from-master-(one-laptop)-to-nodes-(other-laptop)/) by [Eduard Visinescu](https://answers.ros.org/users/38384/eduard-visinescu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Please let me know if there's a way to use the rostopic command from above in laptop 1 (master) without having the package from laptop 2 (nodes).

If you mean: without the nodes, then the answer can only be *yes* if the messages are stored in a separate package (which is a best practice for precisely this reason: use of ROS API without having to compile/install everything else).

If `component_adder` mixes msg/srv/action definitions with nodes in a single package, then the answer would be *no, this is not possible*, unless you are willing to edit the build script and disable compilation of the nodes in `component_adder`.

---

Edit: the above answer is correct in the general / default case.

For the more adventurous approach, see [uts-magic-lab/message_thief](https://github.com/uts-magic-lab/message_thief).

**Note**: this is **not** the recommended way to approach these kind of situations!

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1